# Some sort of unwanted div highlight datepicker materialize-css

Tags: css, cordova, materialize

I'm making a cordova app but today I stumbled on a weird problem. Whenever I close the datepicker (http://materializecss.com/forms.html#date-picker) there is a yellow line at the edge of the webview. (I scrolled a bit down to make it more clear in the picture) [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzskG.png)

I initially thought it was because of some highlight feature on touch devices because when I test my app on a browser (chrome), the border isnt there.

In the css I've disabled highlight like this (though it didn't work):

```
*{
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); ` and `outline:none`? Also do Inspect Element and check if the styles are being accidentally overriden.

Comment: Thx man, it fixed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `outline:none;` in the css did the job.